# How to get all app model based applications in SCCM without WMI?

Tags: c#, wcf, wmi, sccm

With SCCM transitioning to APP model apps, instead of the original package model ([appmodel vs packagemodel](https://www.windowsmanagementexperts.com/sccm-2012-applications-vs-packages/sccm-2012-applications-vs-packages.htm)), I’m investigating how a legacy application built as a windows service using c# can interact with these app model applications. I would typically just use WMI operations to call the CCM_APPLICATION class, but the problem is this is a windows service running as system, so WMI is not really an option. Previously we got around this by using [the UIResourcemgr DLL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/system-center/developer/cc145211%28v%3Dmsdn.10%29) which offers us an interface to perform SCCM interactions. However this DLL is outdated and doesn’t seem to fetch the apps I need. So is there an updated DLL i can leverage to call app model apps much like The CCM_APPLICATION class would’ve gotten me or do I need to find a way to offload this work to the client side not the service side?